# Understanding why GeODin is not found?

Tags: qgis

I have faced with a problem to run QGIS 2.14, and 2.18 version.

During reloading it pops up an error message called 'GeODin is not found'.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is a problem with a plugin. Try to remove this GeODinQGIS Plugin with the Extension manager. If the error still occurs, check your .qgis/python/plugins/ folder in your home directory - if you find a GeODinQGIS Folder (or similar), then delete it.